# Cannot parse array into defined type

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I am using following puppet class

```
class myclass{

      $foo = [{"id" => "bar", "ip" => "1.1.1.1"}, {"id" => "baz", "ip" => "2.2.2.2"}]

      map {$foo:}

     define map () { notify {$name['id']: } }

}
```

But this gives me

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Could not intern from pson: Could not convert from pson: Could not find relationship target "Change_config::Map[ip1.1.1.1idbar]"
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

What is the reason for this ?

Regards,
Malintha Adikari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array contains hashes. The resource declaration syntax works only for arrays of strings.

```
 $foo = ["bar", "baz"]

 map {$foo:}

 define map () { notify {$name: } }
```

If you want to pass data with each resource title, you need to

1. build a hash of your data, not an array of hashes
2. use the `create_resources` function

Untested example code:

```
$foo = { 
  "bar" => { "ip" => "1.1.1.1" }, 
  "baz" => { "ip" => "2.2.2.2" },
}

create_resources('map', $foo)

define map ($ip="") { notify { "$name has ip $ip": } }
```

Comment: this gives me an error err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Cannot find definition Map on node

Comment: I asked the question with my real scenario in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351350/cannot-create-files-inside-defined-type. Please look in to that kindly

Comment: If this answer has helped you, please consider voting and accepting it.